# Git fetch working in SSH mode but fails in HTTPS under jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, ssh, https

We are trying to build our code through Jenkins.
The build process works fine if the git repo links are provided for SSH.

However if I change it to HTTPS, it gives an error during one of the fetch commands.

Here is the error snap:

git.exc.GitCommandError: Cmd('git') failed due to: exit code(128)
  cmdline: git fetch -v origin private/release/release_rc
  stderr: 'fatal: could not read Password for 'https://xyz.auto.builder@abcd-efg.jkl.mnop.net': No such device or address'
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

Comment: I have deliberately changed the URL to in par with the company policy

Comment: How have you stored the password?

Comment: Removing extension '.git' from the repo link ,solves the problem.

Comment: You mean in Jenkins Git plugin section? You should post that detail along with resolution and mark it as answer. Will help others.